# Swift unrecognized selector sent to instance in custom class

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, selector, uipickerview

I keep getting an "'-[UITableView numberOfComponentsInPickerView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance" error referencing a method in one of my custom UITableViewCell classes, and I can't seem to figure out why. I've searched through stack overflow but can't find an answer related to my situation. Any ideas? Thanks!

```
public class PickerTableViewCell:UITableViewCell, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

var pickerData:[Array<Int>] = []

@IBOutlet weak var picker: UIPickerView!

public func configure(data:[Array<Int>]) {
    pickerData = data
}

// Picker functions
public func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return pickerData.count
}
public func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return pickerData[component].count
}
public func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    return String(pickerData[component][row])
}
```

}

Comment: Please show the line you call the method and the error occurs

Comment: It looks like you have incorrectly assigned the picker view's datasource as the `UITableView` rather than the cell.  Please show the code where you create the picker view and assign it's datasource

Comment: @matt I looked at all the threads I could find (upwards of 10, including some objc ones) about the error, but they all had different solutions because the error is so widespread.

Comment: @Paulw11 thank you! I had assigned the delegate in the storyboard, and must have mis-dragged.

Comment: @matt http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24094620/unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-in-swift How is the solution here the same as the solution to my question?  (this is not me getting mad, this is a legitimate question because I'm new to programming!) Thanks!

Comment: That isn't exactly the same cause (in terms of a button action method) but it *is* the same cause in that the method that was invoked couldn't be found. You need to know "why". In your case if you look at the error message you see that the method `numberOfComponentsInPickerView:` was invoked on a `UITableView` instance.  So you ask the question "why would that method be invoked on a UITableView?" - The method in question is a picker view data source method, so that means that somewhere you assigned a UITableView as a picker view's data source

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks, that makes a ton of sense. I think the fact that a lot of the answers didn't explain much and just gave code solutions confused me. I assume I should delete this question now? Thanks again.

Comment: Don't delete the question.  It isn't an especially *bad* question, and the fact that you had the problem means that someone else may too - they may search and find your question and get the answer - this is the whole point of SO - not just to answer your question but help others too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the error message you see that the method `numberOfComponentsInPickerView:` was invoked on a `UITableView` instance.

So you ask the question "why would that method be invoked on a `UITableView`?"

The method in question is a picker view data source method, so that means that somewhere you assigned a UITableView as a picker view's data source, so that when the picker view was displayed the method call was made against a class (`UITableView`) that hadn't implemented the delegate method.

In your case it was a simple drag-drop error in Interface Builder.