# Swift selector to protocol function?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have code like this:

```
protocol FooP {
   ...
}

extension FooP {
   func doFoo() {
      print("foo")
   }
   func doFoo(timer: NSTimer) {
      doFoo()
   }
}
class A : NSObject, UITableViewDataSource, FooP {
   var timer : NSTimer?

   ...

   func startUpdating() {
      timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(
         1.0,
         target: self,
         selector: Selector("doFoo:"),
         userInfo: nil, 
         repeats: true
      )
   }
}
```

Unfortunately it crashes when I start timer the program crashes with

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[xyz.A doFoo:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fb2041c4ac0'
```

How i can make it work (I want to keep implementation of doFoo inside protocol)?

If I move doFoo into A class definition everything works fine, but as i said i want to implement this function inside protocol.

In other words  I need selector that says

```
"Hey I point to function named "doFoo" that is implemented as extension to FooP"
```

Right now selector seems to say

```
"Hey I point to function named "doFoo" that is implemented in A class"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Unrecognized selector sent to instance" in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24094620/unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-in-swift)

Comment: Nope my problem is that timer do not see functions implemented as extensions to protocol

Comment: i had the same problem. do you have a solution yet? i am just implementing the funciton in my class for now

Comment: I hadn't found better solution

Answer (score 1):

Try to play in your playground. Your trouble is, that there is no possibility to define @objc func in protocol extension. So, see possible workaround

```
import XCPlayground
XCPlaygroundPage.currentPage.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
import Foundation

protocol FooP {
}

extension FooP {
    func doFoo() {
        print("foo")
    }
    func doFoo(timer: NSTimer) {
        print("dofoo")
        doFoo()
    }
}
class A: FooP {
    var timer : NSTimer?
    @objc func foo(timer: NSTimer) {
        doFoo(timer)
    }
    func startUpdating() {
        timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(
            1.0,
            target: self,
            selector: "foo:",
            userInfo: nil,
            repeats: true
        )
    }
}

let a = A()
a.startUpdating()
```

Why it works for you if you move doFoo inside class A? That is because your class inherits from NSObject, so @objc keyword is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, `NSTimer` and the whole `Selector()` business are Objective-C stuff and do work in Swift domain thanks to bridging.  However, Swift's default protocol implementations are *not* bridged to Objective-C wonderland (yet), and that's why your timer fails.  Basically, from Objective-C perspective objects of type `A` do *not* respond to a selector `doFoo:`, period.

So, report this use-case to swift-evolution for the long-term solution.  Short-term, use some sort of a workaround.

BTW, you might find it interesting to read (or even participate) in this [thread](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20160104/005312.html).