# In Xcode, I received an error that read.... -[Dicee_iOS13.ViewController Button:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7f8fd55092b0

Tags: ios, xcode, button

I am new to Xcode and apple all together. I am working through https://www.udemy.com/course/ios-13-app-development-bootcamp as I was working on a dice app, my button did not work it just gave me an error. The goal of the app is for the button to roll the dice when it is pressed. Right now I am just trying to get the code to run without an error. [The picture bellow shows the error and were it is coming up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbtrk.png)

```
@IBAction func rollButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    print("button got tapped")
}
```

[The last line of code is my button code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbtrk.png)

I have tried reconnecting it but is still saying it does not recognize it. I could not find an error like this anywhere else. So, I'm trying every thing I know. Anything Helps. Thanks.

Comment: Hi
Welcome to Stackoverflow. This link might help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24094620/unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

```swift
@IBAction func rollButtonPressed(_ sender: Any) {
  print("button tapped")
}
```

Hi ....I Had exactly the same issue. I deleted the code. Pressed Control (Key) and dragged the roll Botton link back into the code area. this now works. Can't explain how or what the cause was but I deleted the link ( or broke the connection) by right clicking and removing link on the roll button image. Re-dragging link back onto right code page.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, while debugging I found out that when I first made the connection, I did it a head of the instr. I forgot to make it an UIButton. I then deleted it and added it back.

The issue was I never deleted the connection, and it still was still trying to run off the code that did have the type as UIButton, once I deleted the link and redid it, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers don't explain what is causing this, only fixes that could be more clear.

This is caused by only partially clearing the connection you set up for the roll button. You probably deleted the code but did not right-click the button and "x" out on the connection in the storyboard.

I'm guessing you got ahead of the instructor, set it up, then realized she did the control drag configuration slightly different than the previous two dice. You deleted the code and tried again, however, when you ran the code it errored.

To fix the issue, you must also right-click the roll button in the storyboard viewer and then click the little "x"'s to clear the connections. The multiple uncleared connections are breaking it first and causing the error because it wants to run the connection but the code no longer exists from when you only partially cleared it and so it errors before running the second connection you set up.

Goodluck with the rest of the course!